# How to build two EARs using maven, one with modules packed and the other unpacked?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I am building an EAR that contains unpacked WARs. But due to [a bug in Arqullian Test Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16806846/1667977), I need to build another EAR, that will look the same, but the WARs inside will be packed. I thought of using two different executions of `maven-ear-plugin`, but I always get two completely the same EARs. This is because when maven copies the packed (or unpacked) WARs into build directory, it won't overwrite them with the unpacked (or packed) versions in the next execution. This is the relevant part of my `pom.xml` (inside `maven-ear-plugin` plugin tag).

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>arq</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ear</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>arq</classifier>
                        <unpackTypes>sar</unpackTypes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>main</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ear</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier></classifier>
                        <unpackTypes>war,sar</unpackTypes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

The order of the executions doesn't matter.

I want to tell `maven` to overwrite the WARs (either directories or archives), or maybe find another elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Is it an option to use a separate project/module for integration tests? I prefer this strategy because integration (and acceptance) testing requires workarounds more often than not. If the workaround for Arquillian is build separately you might isolate the problem more easily.

Comment: Yes, this is possible and working, however far from elegant. It means creating a separate maven project with `pom.xml` nearly identical to the original ear project, which is already quite bloated. This copy-pasting workaround is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: I see. Have you tried to set a different `finalName` or `outputDirectory` ( see [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html) ) for the Arquillian specific execution?

Comment: I knew I am missing something obvious. It was not `outputDirectory`, but `workDirectory` that must be set in the execution, but you set me or the right path. Please post is as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(team work, see comments):

Setting a different `workDirectory` helps.  ([see Maven EAR plug-in docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html))